# Does Oracle 11.2 handle DDL with CRLF end of line characters different than Oracle 10.2?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ddl, oracle11gr2

I have a few .SQL files that contain a CREATE PROCEDURE ... that have Carriage Return / Line Feeds as the EOL characters. In Oracle 11.2 this works fine.  In Oracle 10.2 I get a PLS-00103 error.  If I replace the EOL characters with just LFs it works find in 10.2.

I see no obvious net articles speaking about any differences in the SQL parser between Oracle 10.2 and 11.2.

Is there a difference or a setting I am missing?

Comment: Are they both running on the same operating system?

Comment: Which tool do you use to run those scripts?

Comment: 10.2 = Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production on RH5.8

11.2 = Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production on RH6.8

We write in a language no one knows, Visual Dataflex, and use a 3rd party middleware product to connect to Oracle called Mertech.  Same PGM and .SQL files just different back in DBs versions and OS. 

Wait.... I ran it from WIndows 10 to connect to 11.2 and Windows 2008R2 to connect to 10.2... Perhaps that is where the difference is?